# What is the latest estimated probability for the self assembly of a primitive cell?

Tags: theoretical-biology, bioenergetics

Peusner ([Concepts in Bioenergetics, 1974](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Concepts_in_Bioenergetics.html?id=aXqTuAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)) [estimated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_statistics) the [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) of the [self-assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_self-assembly) of a primitive cell as $10^{-254}$. Given how much more we now know about cell biology, what is the latest consensus figure? I've found lots of papers and discussions about the mechanics but I haven't seen anyone else put a figure on it.

Comment: Is a primitive cell a [protocell or protobiont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocell) in this context, or more like a modern cell as we find them today? Or something else?

Comment: I hate to say it, but if you can’t find such a figure, nobody here is likely to — probably because such calculations are not testable and have no relevance to experimental biologists. And why give a link to the Wikipedia entry for “cell biology”?

Comment: @Galen The best description I've found is "partitioned units resembling modern cells."

Comment: @David Surely it can be modeled?

Comment: I imagine so. But the devil is in the assumptions. It's all so much medieval theology — angels on dancing on the head of a pin. Biology is a practical subject.

Comment: @David I can't believe no-one's even ball-parked it though, there must be someone who has run the numbers.

Comment: It is easily the case that no one has 'run the numbers'. As David points out, there are different combinations of assumptions one can make. I rate them somewhere above "medieval theology" since we can impose physical laws and established statistical trends, but  even so they are quite varied and speculative. Even if some calculations have been done, it isn't clear how a 'best' figure could be chosen.

Comment: @Galen I can't quite dismiss it as theology either. Surely it's a significant factor in the estimation of the extent of extraterrestrial life?

Comment: There might be a marginal probability of life forming in a uniformly sampled region of space, but I doubt we are close to having such a number that we can have confidence in. [Assembly theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_theory) seems like a more promising approach to identifying biosignatures, but that approach is still in its infancy.

Comment: I think an explanation of why this would be almost impossible, as a 'frame challenge', would be useful. .

Comment: See [*What is a frame challenge?*](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge) and [*Does Stack Exchange allow for answers which question the validity or stance of the original question?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t).

Comment: @user438383 It's possible to estimate badly but it's not impossible to collate all of the developments of the last 50 years and update Peusner's estimate. If he was even half right then we are alone in the universe so it's not an inconsequential question.

Comment: @Jack - Does it really *matter* if we are alone in the universe? Does life elsewhere out there give meaning to our existence? If a million lifeforms exist that we will never encounter (a strong possibility, that latter phrase), does it mean our lives are less meaningful? It's interesting to speculate, but that's all it is, speculation.

Comment: @anongoodnurse It matters in the sense that it ceases to be an area of worthwhile research.

Comment: @Jack - I'm not sure of its worth right now. We have war, poverty, disease, starvation, lack of potable water, etc. Many things to take care of at home on our little watery rock.

Comment: It's not a *useful* question, as a majority of the discussion above has been trying to point out to you.

Comment: @MattDMo Of course it’s a useful question, because it’s a proxy for how much we actually know about the associated processes.

Comment: It's not a useful question *for this site*. It has 3 downvotes and 5 closure votes (some may be by the same people). I'd say that's a pretty clear consensus by the established users. And, as Maximilian points out in their answer, it's not the only way life could have evolved, so I'm not sure it's that useful in general. At any rate, I'm not going to debate this any more. You asked a question in a comment, I answered it. You can agree with it or not.

Comment: @MattDMo But how would you even compare two different accounts without calculating either probability? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

I think that it's worth directly examining the [citations of the book in question](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=0&hl=en&as_sdt=5,48&sciodt=0,48&cites=7592152060884320285&scipsc=).

In doing so, I [found the following quote](https://academic.oup.com/femsre/article/25/5/573/500450):

> The abundance of the first 31 elements in the Periodic Table on Earth and in the known universe is highly correlated: Peusner [11] estimated the self-assembly of a primitive cell occurring as a spontaneous act, where the molecules and elements were present at a specific location on the Earth in a suitable sequence, as 10−254. Conversely, even a highly improbable event can occur. This only adds to the paucity of information and the confusion we struggle with when researching the origin of life. According to Peusner [11] **this suggests the origin of life and evolution occurred in an ordered manner from the simple to the more complex.**

In other words, there is a counterfactual to "self-assembly of a primitive cell" for the origin of life. Peusner himself seems to have considered this a somewhat ridiculous straw man according to this reading, not that I've directly read his book- in other words, abiogenesis via spontaneous generation of cells isn't constantly happening all around us, which hopefully isn't news to anyone.

Instead, the argument goes, you could gradually add components until you ended up with a primitive cell. This would presumably involve a sequence of still-improbable-but-much-more-probable events. This would presumably involve the [RNA world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_world) or other such cases as intermediate steps to a cell. I am not sure what the probability of such things is, but [there does seem to be some amount of speculative literature on this out there](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3495036/).

*NB: I infer from the comments that you are mostly interested in xenobiology and the probability of other life existing, and are only interested in the cell assembly probability as the presumed path to the existence of life elsewhere in the universe.*

Comment: 'gradually add components until you ended up with a primitive cell' sounds ridiculously panglossian without any math derived from established biological and physical processes. With 50 years' of additional research, we must be able to make a more educated guess, but it seems like the answer to my specific question is that there is no more current estimate.

Comment: @Jack I think the point is that it's less panglossian than "cell from nothing", which seems to be what you're asking about. The lack of additional research on "cell from nothing" might be taken as a clue of how viable a path it's considered to be, whereas origin-of-life research is alive and well on other possibilities.